# Are division algebras necessarily unital?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

As per links like this [one](https://www.mathphysicsbook.com/mathematics/abstract-algebra/generalizing-vectors/division-algebras/), it seems that division algebras (when unital) are defined in terms of the existence of inverses equalling a neutral element $1$, whereas [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) defines it in terms of "division to an arbitrary $x$". Is there a difference here? Is the difference that the Wikipedia definition applies to a non-unital algebra too?

Incidentally, in the first given link there is a requirement that the algebra be finite-dimensional. Is there any reason for this? I can't see what doesn't go through if this is relaxed.

Comment: Allowing nonassociative algebras would go against the Frobenius theorem. [consider 3-space with cross product] So in a way your question is one of definition.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I do not know of this theorem. @coffeemath

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: The theorem I mentioned is on wiki, see link above.

Comment: Briefly Frobenius theorem says only division algebras over reals are the reals, the complex numbers, and the quaternions. All of these are associative and have unit elements for the multiplication. But the cross product on 3-space would qualify your other definition as a nonassociative algebra with no multiplicative identity over the reals of dimension 3.

Comment: I don't understand mention of the cross product here. I guess I'm wondering about whether there are nonunital division algebras, and surely the answer there is yes right? Is that why we have the more general Wikipedia definition I mentioned? @coffeemath

Comment: EE18.. I'm sure the nonassociative cases have been studied, one I know of being the octonians, 8 dimensional over the reals. My point is only that there appears to be some differences of terminology regarding whether associativity should be required. In the Frobenius case associativity is required. [also you asked about cross product, it is the usual thing studied in calc 3. [It is known associativity implies existence of multiplicative identity element]

Comment: "It is known associativity implies existence of multiplicative identity element" This I did not know! I will look this up, thank you! Edit: I looked it up and could not find "associative implies unital". Can you provide a reference? @coffeemath

Comment: See the second sentence of the "Definitions" section right at the top of your linked wiki article.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148001/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-ee18).